# How successful was the Anti-Imperialist League?

Tags: united-states, imperialism

America's imperialist era was characterized by informal empires and the annexation of various states, such as the Philippines. Eventually, people such as [William J. Bryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Jennings_Bryan) found out about the immoral methods used by Americans to gain this territory. He helped form the Anti-Imperialist League because of this.

How successful was the League in getting the message out to others about American methods?

Comment: Apparently it was not successful, because it was dissolved in 1920, while the complete independence of Philippines was not obtained until 1935 or even 1946. As I understand the US never intended to permanently annex Philippnes.